# Is it possible to shift frame of reference to an electron?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, observers

We can see the world from different perspectives, from inertial frames to non-inertial frames. All that works very well but suppose I want to see the world from electron’s perspective then would I be able to do that, given the fact electron mass is very less and as an observer I will be subjected to Heisenberg uncertainty principle? Can an observer be at rest with respect to electron? Similarly can I see the world from the perspective of proton, neutron, atom, molecule, lattice, insect size frame, human body etc …

Is it possible to shift frame of reference to any entity?

PS : I asked the same question, as in the title ,to ChatGPT. Following was the response , which surprised me:

> Yes, in physics, it is possible to shift the frame of reference to an
> electron. By doing so, physicists can analyze the behavior and
> interactions of the electron with other particles or fields from the
> electron's own point of view, helping to gain a deeper understanding
> of its properties and dynamics within various systems.

Comment: You can see the sun from the earth's point of view, even if it is vastly more massive. Of course you may express the variables of Schroedinger's equation in any frame you choose, instead of the center of mass frame employed in textbooks, which is quite close to the nucleus' frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a future way of interpreting quantum mechanics such that we can shift frames of reference to any particle, like you're suggesting here, but for right now that's not a thing that makes sense.  The terminology "shifting frame of reference" is shorthand for "changing coordinates".  When we can approximate an object as a point that is moving along a trajectory, we can say that a set of coordinates is in the frame of that object if the spatial coordinates are always zero relative to that object.  Since, as you pointed out, an electron at the microscopic level can't be approximated as a point moving along a trajectory, there is no well-defined set of coordinates corresponding to its frame of reference.